# Azure web apps default document index wildcard

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I'm deploying my angular APP to azure web apps which works fine. Actually my index file gets referenced each build by gulp to something like index-e78hs45g.html
Is there a way to automatically change the default document of web apps to this Name or use a Wildcard like index-*.html? So i don't have to change it by Hand in each deploy?

Edit: due to questions - the unique filename is to prevent browsercaching in New deployments.

Comment: so there is not an index.html?  No other  index-soomething3223.html ? just one index-XXXXX.html file?

Comment: Yes there is just an index-xxxx and some folders

Answer (score 0):

I would make your current version always build index.html. I am not sure I follow why your gulp script is doing a unique file name everytime?

Comment: It's done to prevent browsercaching for New deployments